# magento 2: how to checked use default value for product status programmtically?

Tags: database, product-attribute, magento2.4, programmatically

I have to update and checked checkbox for use default field for product status. But I do not know how to update and checked that checkbox ?
[image]
here is my code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $productId = 1;
        $status = 1;
        $store = 1;

        $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

        try {
            $product->setStoreId($store);
            $product->setStatus($status);
            $product->save();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "Error Id : " . $productId;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

fast solution, check this link
https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-check-if-use-default-value-checked-for-a-product-attribute-value-in-magento-2/

cheers